# Four-letter words from the word MEDITERRANEAN such that the first letter is R and the fourth letter is E

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> If the four letter words (need not be meaningful) are to be formed using the letters from the word MEDITERRANEAN such that the first letter is R and the fourth letter is E, then the total number of all such words is :

My attempt:

$4$ different letters, $3E, 2R, 2A, 2N$. i.e. total $8$ varieties, out of $13$ letters.

Since the first and the fourth letter is fixed, so the intermediate two letters are to be filled from $11$ remaining letters. But we can't just do $^{11}C_2$ as all $11$ are not different. Also, $^8C_2$ won't make sense either as that won't include the option of $2N$ or $2A$ etc.

How to go about it?

Comment: After using one R and one E, we have $11$ letters left, M,E,D,I,T,E,R,A,N, where E, A, and N each occur twice.   Why do you say there are only $4$ letters left?

Comment: @saulspatz I don't think I said that. Have I implied that anywhere?

Comment: What does "4 different letters" mean then?

Comment: @saulspatz MDIT

Comment: Is it restricted that letters are not to be repeated?

Comment: Result is $8\cdot7+3$, where the three added cases are those formed by two equal letters.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Do you mean T can be used more than once or do you mean R can be used more than once? I think it's implicit that the former is not allowed, the latter is allowed.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Thanks.

Comment: I think both of them are not allowed; simply stating, "the four letters should be distinct".

Comment: @ultralegend5385 it is not mentioned that the letters should be distinct. So, 2R, 2N etc can be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two middle places are to be filled from

$$ \{ M,D,T,I,R \} \quad \{ 2\cdot E,2\cdot A,2\cdot N \}$$

We have following two cases :

1. Different letters : $(^5 P_2) + (^3P_2) + 5\cdot3\cdot2 = 56$

or as pointed by @Intelligenti pauca, simply $8 \cdot 7 = 56$

2. Same letters : $^3 C_1$

Total $= 59$

Comment: Hi. Can you elaborate on $5\cdot3\cdot2?$

Comment: It's the overlap, 1 from both sets.

Comment: @arbee another way to look at it, $8$ letters in $2$ places give $8 \times 7 = 56$ arrangements without repeat. Add $3$ to it.

Comment: @MathLover Thanks.